# TypeORM returns empty array when querying MongoDB for date

Tags: mongodb, typeorm

I have the following query that is supposed to get the objects that have a future hospitalizedUntil date from my MongoDB:

```
        return await this.hospitalRepository.find({
        where: {
            hospitalizedUntil: MoreThanDate(new Date(), EDateType.Datetime)
        }
    });
```

Where MoreThanDate:

```
const MoreThanDate = (date: Date, type: EDateType) => MoreThan(format(date, type));
```

However, this query doesn't return any objects, even though there is an object in the Mongo where hospitalizedUntil is in the future:
(Current datetime: 2020-08-28T17:11:09.888Z)

```
[
  Hospital {
    _id: 5f492efd50e81f63dc60c5d3,
    discordId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    hospitalizedUntil: 2020-08-28T18:51:17.627Z,
    reason: 'Was robbed',
    hospitalizedBy: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
]
```

I've also tried to use the Between operator:

```
    where: {
        hospitalizedUntil: Between(new Date(), new Date('9999-12-31'))
    }
```

But this also returned an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and solved it by using the native mongoDB query.

```
hospitalizedUntil: { $gte: format(new Date(), EDateType.Datetime) }
```

I think those functions just don't work on mongoDB (although I've not found anything related to that issue)